# Mock location when using iOS Core Location Manager

Tags: ios, core-location

Is it possible to mock a location when using Core Location Manager like you can in Android? I want to do this so we can see simulated behaviors when a user is a different location.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using at least Xcode 4.2 and iOS SDK 5+, you can launch your app and in the simulator you can click the `debug` menu, then click the `location` option, the click `custom location`. You can then enter a custom latitude and longitude. They also have options for Freeway Drive, City Bicycle Ride, and City Run these all emulate the device moving.

Comment: I want to do it in the app, not simulator. Possible?

Comment: Not possible without jailbreaking.

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely simulate location on the device if you run from Xcode. After the app compiles, installs, and starts running, find the "Debug Bar" at the bottom of the window (or just above the Console, if you have that showing). There is a small "Location" icon that reveals a menu of locations, plus an option to load a GPX file if you want something more complex. You can also edit your build scheme to include a default location in the Run phase (i.e., for every run, not just when you set the location with the menu in the Debug bar).

One thing to note, if you're using your personal device and not a dedicated development device: the custom location Xcode sets persists even after you disconnect from Xcode. So if you leave your desk with your phone, you may find it still thinks it's in whatever location you simulated; restarting will clear this setting, and allow you to use your device normally.